# Can Python perform the 'replace' function across lines?

Tags: python, replace, newline, data-processing

I would like to replace only the 3rd `}` in the below script to `]`.

```
 "objectLocationHeight" : "46.500000",
    "text" : "1494"
  },
  "timestamp" : "2015-10-09 12:50:58",
  "eventType" : "keyboardOnAnsBox",
  "action" : "endTyping"
}
  },
"submitTime" : "
```

The following is the target result

```
 "objectLocationHeight" : "46.500000",
    "text" : "1494"
  },
  "timestamp" : "2015-10-09 12:50:58",
  "eventType" : "keyboardOnAnsBox",
  "action" : "endTyping"
}
  ],
"submitTime" : "
```

However, it seems that the 'replace' function can only work within a line and I couldn't get the desired result with

```
str1= str.replace("},\n\"submit","],\n\"submit")
```

May I know if there is other syntax that allows me to perform `replace` across lines?

Comment: i think the problem with this is that the new line character might not necessarily be `\n` (it could be `\r` or both or something else) and there may be whitespace that you don't take into account. regex might work a little better cuz you could use `or` operands and `\s*` to strip any whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you need to replace any `}` in `]` in a document if it appears before `"submitTime"`.

You could use backwards document reading and a boolean flag to insure that the previous line was the relevant one:

```
for line in reversed(open("filename").readlines()):
    cond = line.startswith("\"submitTime\"")
    if cond and line.startswith("},"):
        new = line.replace("},","],")
        print new
        cond = False
    else:
        print line
```

Maybe there exist more elegant solutions, but this should work. Of course, you could substitute `print` by opening an output file and writing into it with `fout.write(line)`.

Answer (score 0):

The replace method itself takes only another optional parameter, "max". So, I would say that there is no immediate way to do it without some coding.

How to do it, then? Well, I assume you are reading the whole text in the 'str' variable. What you *can* do is simply iterate over the str line, and once reached the 3rd line, apply the replace method to the line.

Something like:

```
counter = 0
for line in str.splitlines(): 
  if "}" in line:
    counter += 1
  if counter == 2:
    line = line.replace("}", "]")
  # do something with line here ...
```

I don't like this solution, though. It's very very specific to your sample, but you didn't provide any other kind of information.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Sorry that I didn't provide enough information. The code was intended to convert the bracket just before "submitTime", so counting in the above way may not be suitable. But I think for loop may be useful too!

Comment: You are welcome! The point is that next time you should also specify more details, e.g., how many times "submitTime" appears in the file?